# Change collection view cell sizing for chat app

Tags: ios, swift

I make a chat with using collection view. The cell dynamically changes depending on the text. I did it using `preferredlayoutattributes...` method in the cell file.

If I do sizing by height, then everything is fine, but the label stretches wider than the text. If I do it by all size, then I have problems with layout.

What am I missing? I use storyboard for the entire view and xib for the cell.

In ViewController I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout! {
    didSet {
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - sideInset, height: 80)
}
```

In cell file:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
    var newFrame = layoutAttributes.frame

    newFrame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
    // newFrame.size = size
    layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    let widthOfText:Int = Int(yourTextsList[indexPath.row].width(by: font)) + 32

    let height = 80
    return CGSize(width: widthOfText + 24, height: height)
}
```

and this is for String Extension:

```
extension String {
    /// Avalilable width for text with specified font
    /// - Parameter font: Font
    /// - Returns: Text width
    func width(by font: SFWFont) -> CGFloat {
        var textWidth: CGFloat = 0
        for element in self {
            let characterString = String(element)
            let letterSize = characterString.size(withAttributes: [.font: font])
            textWidth += letterSize.width
        }
        return textWidth + 1
    }
}
```